# How do I downgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have enabled HWE and I have been upgrading up to 14.04.4. I need openCL and so fglrx, therefore I cannot upgrade to -lts-xenial

Since support for 14.04.4 / -lts-wily ended, I went back to the original linux-generic and xserver-xorg packages. However, lsb_release still indicates 14.04.5 as the version, and users are warned of unsupported system at each login.

What string/config needs to change to make Ubuntu aware that it has now reverted to 14.04 and it is no longer at 14.04.5?

Comment: "Since support for 14.04.5 / -lts-wily ended" Sorry? That is supported up to April 2019.

Comment: I see: This is a different issue. It should say 14.04.4 because I installed -lts-wily but never -lts-xenial (14.04.5), yet lsb_release somehow believes I did.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/issue` file is in the package `base-files`, you might want to downgrade it as well. However, 14.04 is not supported any more than 14.04.5 so the warning might stay even after this downgrade.

Comment: No, it is not that. I changed /etc/issue and rebooted, but lsb_release still reports 14.04.5